# PHp excel reader :databse table shows mutliple rows with empty values

Tags: php, excel, import, excel-2007

I have coded  a php script to import excel sheet data to mysql database..code is 80% correct ..no errors shows..also all excel sheet data were added to the table...but problem is databse table shows some empty cells with value of 0..many no of rows appeared....
* here is the phpmyadmin table image:[visit this] https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpNTG.png
* here is my excel sheet has only 4 rows of data..
* here is my php code :download from this mediafire link : http://www.mediafire.com/?civnwaiolevl7yj

**this code is works..no problem abou that...problem is out put of this code....
**I think u all are to can understand my problem...how can i stop saving those empty rows in my db table...please help me to recover this problem.....**

Comment: I think little bit changing this code ..will be a slution..plzz help me...thxx in advanced...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the value of $arr[$i][1] and only do your insert if it's not empty

Comment: ohhh thxxx mr.Mark Baker..u have go it absolutely right...thank u so much.... :) if(empty($arr[$i][1]){//then insert data..}

Comment: before insert data check ...

$a=$arr[$i][1];
if(empty($a)){

//insert data....
}

that's all.....