# How to Show No data Found in Excel?

Tags: excel, export, phpexcel

I am using PHPexcel library for export data to excel. It's working fine. The problem is it displays empty cells when no data is in the database. I want to show `No data found` or any other message instead of empty Cells or alternatively when the export button is clicked show alert box with some message without download excel file. How can I do it? can anyone try to help me?

Thank you...

Comment: Can you post the PHP code you are using to export the DATA?

Comment: Please take a look at the below link. May be this could help you. [PHp excel reader :databse table shows mutliple rows with empty values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469925/php-excel-reader-databse-table-shows-mutliple-rows-with-empty-values)

Answer (score 0):

You can use IF ELSE condition when you entering data in cell.
If Database value found is Blank then Write Your Message in that cell.
Otherwise write database value to that cell.